# mcrypt CBC unable to access outside www

Tags: php, directory, fopen, mcrypt

From a novice:
In currently experimenting with mcrypt CBC.

I have no issues getting recall.mcrypt.php to recall mcrypt.php file inside the same directory but because of best practices and security needs, I'm placing mcrypt.php outside the directory using:

```
$file = fopen("/opt/lampp/test.mcrypt/mcrypt.php","r");
```

In doing so I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'phpFreaksCrypto' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/CCS/mcrypt/recall.mcrypt.php on line 6
```

mcrypt.php

```
if (realpath(__FILE__) == realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
{
// tell people trying to access this file directly goodbye...
exit('This file can not be accessed directly...');
}

class phpFreaksCrypto
{
// content is located here
}
```

The settings for mcyrpt.php have been set to read. Maybe my confusion lies in fopen even though I thought this command is used for this very purpose or is there a command that better recalls mcyrpt.php in this type of situation.

All insights and suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is mcrypt.php comming from? In order to include a .php file for additional functionality from this file you will have to use the statements include, require etc.

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: seems I got it working with  require_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/CCS/mcrypt/recall.mcrypt.php'); Is it same to reveal the full path since it's above the root directory?

Comment: I've been looking into $keys, $hashes and $salt. mcrypt.php is going to hold the algorithm.